# What should I check when trying to fix a PHP website which is loading slowly?

Tags: php, performance

we have created a website as hobby using PHP with minimum budget and we are facing a problem where the main page is taking 30 to 60 seconds to load.

We checked with the server and it's fine from their end. Can anyone provide help/guidance in fixing this?

Comment: Look closely at what the PHP is *doing* and see what's taking so long.

Comment: Are all the pages slow or only a few ones ? If it affects only some pages, give us the code

Comment: Ask a specific question, you will get the answer.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your php code to see where it might be taking a long time to process?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [yslow ad-don](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/). it will give you a specific list of things on the website which needs modification. with this you can make changes so that your website can load faster.

Comment: don't forget to check your php and apache logs.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give a lot of information, so that makes it difficult to answer your question, but here's a couple things that may slow it down:

- Extraneous MySql queries
- loop that goes longer then expected
- very heavy images. Maybe try lowering the quality of the pictures

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check:**

- Use the Net tab in Firebug to see where the delay is.
- How long are the database queries taking?
- Are you using a PHP framework? If so, which?
- How large is the page? I.e. how many scripts/images are you downloading?
- How much Javascript is on the page? Have you tried turning it ofF?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accelerate my web-site dramatically by getting rid of **gethostbyaddr** function. gethostbyaddr is extremely slow for many IP addresses, especially for these who do not have host name associated to IP. Particularly, by removing all refs to gethostbyaddr page load speed was lowered from **15 seconds** -> **1 second**!

Also, make sure to **do not load pages from third-party servers** in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is that the PHP script is taking 60 seconds to return:

Try to debug what is taking so long, logging or quitting earlier might help. Most of the time it is one place where the script is taking long.

Specially check places with File, Network or Database IO. Check loops!